# Google Search Console says page is "Not on Google" but shows in search results

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

A client asked me to make sure his old, nonexistent pages got removed from the Google search results.

I made sure all the old links returned a 404/410 error or have the `noindex` tag and then used the [Removal Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal) to temporarily block the URLs, hoping to keep them hidden until Google recrawls the site and removes the dead links permanently.

One page, however, continues to show up in the search results and I can't figure out why.

[image: google results]

Even more curious is the fact that when I use [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) to inspect the URL, it tells me the "URL is not on Google".

[image: google search console]

How is that possible if it's showing up in the search results? What can I try to remove this page from the search results?

Comment: By “search results”, do you mean a `site:` search or normal SERP?

Comment: @MrWhite - I mean a `site:` search.

Comment: Well, a `site:` search can often return pages that don't ordinarily appear in normal Google searches, so when GSC reports that the "URL is not on Google" under this scenario, it's not entirely incorrect. Presuambly, if you were to follow this link in the search results, you don't get a valid response, since the page has already been removed right?

Comment: @MrWhite - Correct. It returns a 410 error.

Comment: Is that what GSC is reporting as "Failed: Crawl anomaly"?

Comment: @MrWhite - Could be... https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203#crawl_warning

Comment: @MrWhite - I used the Fetch as Google tool and it tells me the status is "Not found".

Comment: I have the same problem. google says it's not indexed, but it's indexed. I checked from mobile, incognito mode. you can see too by searching How to Delete Telegram Chat on Android. my site nucuta appears in the first page.

Comment: I think google tool has an issue, because I just checked my google analytics and it shows a significant amount of visitors from google to pages that google says not indexed but actually indexed.